# Exclude objects in list in Django

Tags: django, django-related-manager

I'm trying to make a new list of unused/unselected objects, so that I can show in the template what is used, and what is not used.

My model:

```
class Benefit(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Profile(models.Model):
    benefits = models.ManyToManyField(Benefit, blank=True, null=True, related_name="used_benefit")
```

My view:

```
class Profile(TemplateView):
    template_name = "profile/benefits.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(Profile, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['unused_benefits'] = Profile.objects.exclude(pk__in=Profile.benefits.all())
            return context
```

It is something Im not getting, because I get this error: `'ReverseManyRelatedObjectsDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'`

I have tried without `all`, but then I get the error `'ReverseManyRelatedObjectsDescriptor' object is not itterable`

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. What do you mean by unused/unselected objects?

Comment: Have you tried getting Profile objects where benefits are None? Instead of trying to exclude those that are matched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing doesn't make any sense at all. You can't access `benefits.all()` on the Profile class itself, only on an instance of it. What would `Profile.benefits.all()` even mean?

And even if that did work, that would give you a list of Benefits. How could you then use that to exclude Profiles by pk? And then, thirdly, how would that Profile query help you get a list of unused benefits?

If you are trying simply to get a list of Benefits that have no Profiles attached to them, then you actually need to query the Benefits model, not Profile:

```
unused_benefits = Benefits.objects.filter(profile__isnull=True)
```

Comment: This worked after I changed it to: `context['unused_benefits'] = Benefit.objects.filter(used_benefit__isnull=True)`